# Javascript logic for translating a div along the edges of the viewport

Tags: javascript

CodePen with faulty logic: https://codepen.io/zion-off/pen/VwVoYze

I have an HTML page with lots of content, so the height of the page is really long. I have a div that I want to move along the edges of the screen as the user scrolls. Say, the div starts at `top:0; left:0`, and as the user scrolls, it starts moving down, `top` starts increasing. When it has travelled a distance of `window.innerHeight`, it starts moving right, so `left` starts increasing. When the div has travelled a distance of `window.innerWidth`, it starts moving up, `top` begins to decrease. When it has travelled a distance of `window.innerHeight`, it starts moving left, `left` starts decreasing. This should repeat.

Here's what I have so far, but I think the logic is erroneous, because it just travels down, reaches the bottom, the appears at the top again, and starts going down.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var animatedDiv = document.getElementById("animatedDiv");
  var rect = animatedDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
  var xDistance = window.innerWidth - rect.width;
  var yDistance = window.innerHeight - rect.height;

  window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    if ((rect.left == 0) && (rect.bottom != window.innerHeight)) {
      moveDownY();
    }
    if (rect.bottom == window.innerHeight) {
      moveRightX();
    }
    if (rect.right == window.innerWidth) {
        moveUpY();
    }
    if ((rect.top == 0) && (rect.left != 0)) {
        moveLeftX();
    }
  });

  function moveDownY() {
    var distance = window.scrollY % window.innerHeight;
    if (distance <= yDistance) {
      animatedDiv.style.transform = "translateY(" + distance + "px)";
    }
  }
  function moveRightX() {
    var distance = window.scrollY % window.innerWidth;
    if (distance <= xDistance) {
      animatedDiv.style.transform = "translateX(" + distance + "px)";
    }
  }
  function moveUpY() {
    var distance = window.scrollY % window.innerHeight;
    if (distance <= yDistance) {
      animatedDiv.style.transform = "translateY(" + -distance + "px)";
    }
  }
  function moveLeftX() {
    var distance = window.scrollY % window.innerWidth;
    if (distance <= yDistance) {
      animatedDiv.style.transform = "translateX(" + -distance + "px)";
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Add some HTML and CSS in order to create a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by *"This should repeat"*? Any specific amount of times? When the page is fully scrolled down, what should be the position of that box?

Comment: What if the user scrolls back up? Should the div travel in the opposite direction then or should it just continue as before, meaning that if the user scrolls back to the top, the div might be anywhere, not necessarily in its home position?

Comment: Why do you get the `rect` only one instead of inside every scroll tick?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i'm using a scroll event listener, if the user isn't scrolling the div won't be moving. if the div has completed one cycle around the viewport, and it's back at top:0 left:0, it should just start traveling again.

Comment: So, to simplify, you want it to circle the bounds of the viewport, in an anticlockwise direction?

Comment: @DavidThomas I can't believe I didn't think of explaining it like this, but yes, exactly. I just added a CodePen link too.

Comment: @trincot I just added a CodePen. Travel distance is being calculated using window.scrollY % window.innerHeight, so if the user scrolls back up, I think the direction of travel should reverse.

Comment: @trincot window.scrollY % window.innerHeight gives an integer value that increases as the user scrolls down, which in turn increments, say, the `top` attribute of the div, so the div moves down. If the user scrolls up, the integer value decreases, which decrements the `top` attribute, and the div reverses.

Comment: I know what that code does; that is not what I am asking. My question is: what do *you* want to happen? Do you want the div to reverse when user scrolls up, or do you prefer the div to keep going in the same counter clockwise direction no matter which direction the user is scrolling?

Comment: @trincot I want the movement to be in relation to the scroll direction, so that if the user starts scrolling up, the div starts going clockwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that one full cycle consists of two full Y movements and two full X movements, you can calculate the total moving distance of a cycle. Use that modular arithmetic to see what the remainder is when you divide the current vertical scroll value by that full cycle length. That remainder is then to be translated to a position for the `div` element. There are four sides to distinguish, and with some mirroring you can reduce it to two cases really.

Here is an implementation:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const animatedDiv = document.getElementById("animatedDiv");
    const {width, height} = animatedDiv.getBoundingClientRect();

    scrollTo(0, 0); // Make sure to start at the top
    requestAnimationFrame(reposition);

    function reposition() {
        const {clientWidth, clientHeight} = document.documentElement;
        const slackY = clientHeight - height;
        const slackX = clientWidth - width - 1;
        let position = scrollY % ((slackX + slackY) * 2);
        const mirror = position >= slackX + slackY;
        position %= slackX + slackY;
        const x = Math.max(0, position - slackY);
        const y = Math.min(slackY, position);
        animatedDiv.style.top = scrollY + (mirror ? slackY - y : y) + "px";
        animatedDiv.style.left = scrollX + (mirror ? slackX - x : x) + "px";
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", reposition);
});
```

```css
body { height: 10000vh }

#animatedDiv { background: yellow; position: absolute; width: 50px; height: 50px; left: 0, top: 0 }
```

```html
<center><h1>Top of body</h1></center>
<div id="animatedDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I'm so amazed by how you made this work -- thank you so much for taking the time to understand my problem and writing out such an elegant solution. Your kindness is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't know there was a feature like that -- I just accepted it!